# Getting “Bye Bye Big Sur” error on installing Big Sur

Tags: macos, big-sur

My current macOS version is 10.14.6 (18G103). I have downloaded Big Sur from App Store but when I am trying to install, I am getting error "Bye Bye Big Sur" when I click on installer.

[image: Bye Bye Big Sur]

Comment: I suspect we work for the same company.   You can only run what is authorised, says Global IT.

Answer (score 48):

That is not a macOS prompt. The icon is from Jamf, a mobile device management solution used by organisations to control devices. Your IT department has most likely blocked Big Sur. They control the dialog and text content. Contact your company or device administrator.

Comment: Probably, they haven't' approved it yet (as opposed to explicitly blocked) because they need to assess its compatibility with their applications / environments. This is common in device management.

Comment: Though I have to say, that is a remarkably stupid message to print. Printing "Your administrator has disabled updating to macOS Big Sur. If you believe this was done in error, please contact your system administrator." would have been clear and concise and not left users trying again and again, not understanding why it's not working.

Comment: @MechMK1 Admins can be extremely unprofessional in their internal messages and naming conventions. I inherited a system were domain admins were "Supreme Commanderz". Sometimes that behavior leaks out into employee facing areas like this.

Comment: @Logarr Ah, I assumed that that was the default message in the MDMS. If it's custom, then yeah, just unprofessional.